# To set Neutral Permission discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

See, let me explain, suppose if I want to allow a user to send a message in the channel, and he is denied to send the message. I want to set his permission to neutral. But, this code allows the user to send a message. Even he is having `Muted` role.

```py
@commands.command(hidden=False)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels=True, manage_permissions=True)
async def unblock(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason:str=None):
    """To allow the blocked user to send messages that channel."""
    guild = ctx.guild
    
    if member.permissions_in(ctx.channel).send_messages == True: await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} {member.name} is already unblocked. They can send message")
    else: await ctx.channel.set_permissions(member, send_messages=True, reason=f"Action requested by {ctx.author.name}({ctx.author.id}) || Reason: {reason}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply doing `None`

```
# Always allowed
= True

# Neutral
= None

#Always denied
= False
```

Also you don't need `== True`, you can just delete that so it's

```
if member.permissions_in(ctx.channel).send_messages:
```